# Exclude the Time Zone and the reduction of Date in UI Bootstrap Date picker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using UI-bootstrap time picker. What I get from that as the Date is the combination of the day and the time also the date that I'm getting is one less than the actual date I have given as the input. Need a fix for this.

I havent changed any default code which can be seen in the UI-Bootstrap website

Controller.js code

```
 $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  $scope.inlineOptions = {
    customClass: getDayClass,
    minDate: new Date(),
    showWeeks: true
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {

    formatYear: 'yy',
    maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
    minDate: new Date(),
    startingDay: 1
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  function disabled(data) {
    var date = data.date,
      mode = data.mode;
    return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
  }

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.inlineOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate ? null : new Date();
    $scope.dateOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate;
  };

  $scope.toggleMin();

  $scope.open1 = function() {
    $scope.popup1.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.open2 = function() {
    $scope.popup2.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
    $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
  };

  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
  $scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];

  $scope.popup1 = {
    opened: false
  };

  $scope.popup2 = {
    opened: false
  };

  var tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  var afterTomorrow = new Date();
  afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  $scope.events = [
    {
      date: tomorrow,
      status: 'full'
    },
    {
      date: afterTomorrow,
      status: 'partially'
    }
  ];

  function getDayClass(data) {
    var date = data.date,
      mode = data.mode;
    if (mode === 'day') {
      var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
        var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

        if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
          return $scope.events[i].status;
        }
      }
    }

    return '';
  }
```

Code in the web page

```
 <p class="input-group">
<input  type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="formData.SelectFromDate" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" datepicker-localdate/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
</p>
```

Comment: this is because of time zone. why dont you set current time zone while initializing your component,

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Sorry I'm just a beginner for this. What should I do. Where can I set the time zone?

Comment: could you create  a plunker,http://plnkr.co/edit

Comment: It may take a while. Im still trying sorry